# AWS .NET SDK DynamoDB Filter expression by Map values doesn't return any data

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to load data from DynamoDB.
I use FilterExpression and KeyExpression.
If I search by simple value on the top level everything works fine.
However, when I try to filter records by nested map values, I get 0 records.

CurrentCase is an object, Assignments is Dictionary, Setup is Enum.

Here is my code:

```
`Expression filterExpression = new ();
        filterExpression.ExpressionAttributeNames["#Setup"] = "CurrentCase.Assignments.Setup";
        filterExpression.ExpressionAttributeValues[":userId"] = userId;
        filterExpression.ExpressionStatement = "#Setup = :userId";`
```

I tried another way, didn't help. (WHERE CurrentCase.Assignments['Setup'] = 'Id' works in PartyQL):

```
`Expression filterExpression = new ();
        filterExpression.ExpressionAttributeNames["#Setup"] = "CurrentCase.Assignments['Setup']";
        filterExpression.ExpressionAttributeValues[":userId"] = userId;
        filterExpression.ExpressionStatement = "#Setup = :userId";`
```

This is how i call query

```
var queryOperationConfig = new QueryOperationConfig
        {
            PaginationToken = paginationToken,
            Limit = pageSize,
            IndexName = GlobalIndexNames.Cases,
            KeyExpression = keyExpression,
            FilterExpression = filterExpression
        };
    Search search = _dbContext.GetTargetTable<CaseEntity>().Query(queryOperationConfig);
            List<Document> documents = await search.GetNextSetAsync(cancellationToken);
```

[image]

I expect that this request return all records where CurrentCase.Assignments['Setup'] equals userId

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forgive me, im not a .Net coder, but your issue is this:

```
filterExpression.ExpressionAttributeNames["#Setup"] = "CurrentCase.Assignments.Setup";
```

You are essentially setting your var `#Setup` to a String `"CurrentCase.Assignments.Setup"`

It should be:

```
ExpressionAttributeNames = new Dictionary<string, string>
                        {
                          { "#CurrentCase", "CurrentCase" },
                          { "#Assignments", "Assignments" },
                          { "#Setup", "Setup" }                     
                        }
```

```
filterExpression.ExpressionStatement = "#CurrentCase.#Assignments#Setup = :userId";`
```

You may need to restructure the example I gave, but you should get the idea.